# Is there a way to refer to the left hand side of an expression in the right hand side? i.e. after the =

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still pretty new to coding and I've never had any formal training, so this may seem like a dumb question or I may be using the wrong terms so go easy on me...! But I was just wondering:

If when performing an operation is there is a shortcut to refer to the left hand side, within the right, without typing the whole name out again?

E.g. instead of writing something like

```
sheet1.range("Unnecessarily Long Range Name").value = sheet1.range("Unnecessarily Long Range Name").value + 1
```

is there something built in like

```
sheet1.range("Unnecessarily Long Range Name").value = LHS + 1
```

Or could I create some kind of custom function to have that effect?

I'm aware the I could use

```
dim x as range
set x = sheet1.range("Unnecessarily Long Range Name")
x.value = x.value + 1
```

but then it's three lines (every time) and I'd rather do it all in one, I like shortcuts...! :)

Comment: The answer to your question is `No`. You can assign a `Variable` to the range or use the `With` statement to eliminate the requirement to write the "Unnecessarily Long Range Name" twice. Using either method would shorten the code but require an extra 1 to 2 lines of code. Your statement "I'd rather do it all in one" implies that you don't want additional lines of code. You can always use `Ctrl c - Ctrl v` so you don't have to retype the "Unnecessarily Long Range Name".

Comment: Haha it's not so much about the typing, I spend a lot more time staring at my code than typing it! Really it was just about reducing the amount of words on screen while still keeping it clear to read without worrying about having to remember lots of variable names. I think the With statement approach is going to be best for me. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Posted a late answer in addition to DisplayName 's solution via a sub procedure to increment range values like e.g. incr rng as possible short cut; feel free to upvote if helpful - @Flewker :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `With … End With` syntax should do:

```
With sheet1.range("Unnecessarily Long Range Name")
    .value = .Value + 1
End With
```

Comment: It's still three lines.. but I like this because it cuts down on defining lots of variables which was partly what I was getting frustrated with. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You are welcome. As for the _"still three lines"_, you can collapse them into one code line only by concatenating them with a colon (`:`). But, I wouldn't do that, for the sake of readability. I myself am a huge fan of limiting codelines, but sometimes it's really not the preferable solution (when possibile).

Answer (score 0):

**Increment range values by short hand code**

You won't arrive to constructions like i++ in other languages, but using a sub call you could execute the example short cut **`incr`** to increment range values:

```
    incr rng
```

or

```
    incr Sheet1.range("Unnecessarily Long Range Name")
```

If you want to return the result after incrementing you might want to pass an optional variable `by Reference`.

```
    Dim x#
    incr Sheet1.range("Unnecessarily Long Range Name"), x
```

You could change the `increment` value of +`1` by default to any other explicit argument value (e.g. +`100`):

```
    Dim x#
    incr Sheet1.range("Unnecessarily Long Range Name"), x, 100
```

**Non contiguous range areas**

Incrementation would work even if your range reference contains non contiguous areas,  e.g. `Sheet1.Range("A3:A6,B1:F1")`. **Caveat**: In this case an *optional variable* would return only the top most cell value - but you could adapt this easily to your needs.

```
Sub incr(rng As Range, Optional myVar, Optional ByVal Increment = 1)
' Purpose: increments Range values (including dates, empty or null values)
'          but omits formulae or strings
' Note:    increments even non contiguos ranges
' Caveat:  if an optional variable is passed as argument,
'          only the top most cell value in a given range will be assigned
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If VarType(cell) < vbString Then        ' includes empty values and dates, too
        If Not cell.HasFormula Then cell.value = cell.value + Increment
    ElseIf VarType(cell) = vbBoolean Then   ' << optional (toggling between True/FALSE)
        cell.value = Not cell.value         ' << comment out, if to be omitted
    End If
Next cell
If Not IsMissing(myVar) Then myVar = rng.Cells(1, 1).value               ' return the top most cell value
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

To shorten the second approach, you are always able to define and set the value of a variable in the same line with a ":".

```vb
dim x as range: set x = sheet1.range("Unnecessarily Long Range Name")
```

Comment: I didn't know this... it's not quite what I had in mind but I'll definitely be using it in the future! Thanks :)